# Java datagrid with coordinates

Tags: java, loops, datagrid, coordinates

I have a user interface made with Java which asks the user to input 2 coordinates.
The user is entering the coordinates on the map like this:

Lower left corner: 34.00000, -105.00000
Upper right corner: 35.00000, -104.00000

Then the user can also input a length for 1 side. The grid is then computed like this:

```
        int sideLength = 125; // meters
        int distance= Integer.parseInt(txtCoords3.getText()) - Integer.parseInt(txtCoords1.getText());

        int squaresPerLine = distance/ sideLength ;
        int squaresTotal = squaresPerLine * squaresPerLine ;

        int coordinateLeftTopX = Integer.parseInt(txtCoords1.getText());
        int coordinateLeftTopY = Integer.parseInt(txtCoords4.getText());
```

Now I need to get the lower left and upper right coordinates of EVERY squares like shown in the image:

[image]

How can I now iterate through the squareTotal to get squares like in the image above? And how can I get the red marked coordinates from the corners?